# program crashing by inserting a new fragment after returning from activity

Tags: android

i am doing a simple android programming training.
my app holds a ArrayList of persons.
clicking on "get count", starts a new activity for result, and when the user goes back to main activity, it supposed to show the number of persons in a new fragment.
the problem is, that the app crashes when the FragmentManager adds the fragment (in the .commit line).
this is my code:

mainActivity:

```
package com.example.myapp;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Hashtable;

    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        private final int GET_COUNT = 0;
        private Button mAddButton;
        private Button mAddPictureButton;
        private EditText mFirstName;
        private EditText mLastName;
        private EditText mId;

        private ListView listView; 

        protected ArrayList<Person> mPersonList;
        protected ArrayAdapter<Person> mAdapter; 


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            if (mPersonList == null){
                mPersonList = new ArrayList<Person>();
            }

            if (mAdapter == null){
                mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        mPersonList);
                listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }

            mAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
            mAddButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      mId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id);
                      mFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName);
                      mLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastName);

                      Person p1 = new Person(Integer.parseInt(mId.getText().toString()),
                              mFirstName.getText().toString(),
                              mLastName.getText().toString());
                      mPersonList.add(p1);
                      mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                      mId.setText("");
                      mFirstName.setText("");
                      mLastName.setText("");
                  }
              });

            mAddPictureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getCount);
            mAddPictureButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(View v) {

                      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GetCount.class);
                      intent.putExtra("personList", mPersonList);
                      startActivityForResult(intent, GET_COUNT);
                  }
              });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // Check which request we're responding to
            if (requestCode == GET_COUNT) {

                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
                if (fragment == null) {
                fragment = new BlankFragment();
                fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
                }
                TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);
                int count = data.getIntExtra("count", 0);
                tv.setText("" + count);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

mainActivity layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/firstName" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/firstName"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint =""
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lastName" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/lastName"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint =""
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/id" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/id"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint =""
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/getCount" 
            android:id="@+id/getCount"/>

     <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add" 
            android:id="@+id/add"/>
     <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

GetCountActivity:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class GetCount extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_count);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayList<Person> persons = (ArrayList<Person>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("personList");
    int count = 0;
    for (@SuppressWarnings("unused") Person person : persons)
    {
        count++;
    }
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("count", count);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
}

}
```

getCount layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.myapp.GetCount" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/counting" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

countFragment:

```
package com.example.myapp;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass. Activities that contain this fragment
 * must implement the {@link CountFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener}
 * interface to handle interaction events. Use the
 * {@link CountFragment#newInstance} factory method to create an instance of
 * this fragment.
 * 
 */
public class CountFragment extends Fragment {



    public static CountFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        CountFragment fragment = new CountFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public CountFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }

}
```

fragment layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.myapp.CountFragment" >

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

      <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/count" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Person:

```
   package com.example.myapp;

public class Person implements java.io.Serializable{
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(){}

    public Person(int id, String firstName, String lastName){
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName="
                + lastName + "]";
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }


}
```

LogCat:

```
11-04 04:34:10.082: D/libEGL(4656): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
11-04 04:34:10.082: D/(4656): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7f189f8, tid 4656
11-04 04:34:10.110: D/libEGL(4656): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
11-04 04:34:10.114: D/libEGL(4656): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
11-04 04:34:10.222: W/EGL_genymotion(4656): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-04 04:34:10.222: E/OpenGLRenderer(4656): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
11-04 04:34:10.230: E/OpenGLRenderer(4656): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
11-04 04:34:10.230: D/OpenGLRenderer(4656): Enabling debug mode 0
11-04 04:34:39.834: W/EGL_genymotion(4656): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-04 04:34:41.242: D/AndroidRuntime(4656): Shutting down VM
11-04 04:34:41.242: W/dalvikvm(4656): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c1b648)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3367)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3410)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1360)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1378)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:92)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5322)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3363)
11-04 04:34:41.246: E/AndroidRuntime(4656):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:**
Read this article: [IllegalStateException: onSaveInstanceState](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) crash

Check:

```
if (requestCode == GET_COUNT) {
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { // add this check
    // then proceed to whatever you want to do
  }
}
```

Also, make sure that

```
TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);
```

exists, i.e BlankFragment fragment is fully inflated and available before you use it.

Last but not least, i think, you will have to have a `<fragment ... />` section inside this `Framelayout` section - but i am not sure about this part.

```
 <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
```

Comment: I did your two first recommendations, but its still crasing. If you will put the fragment layout inside a <fragment ... /> section , the fragment will be static (you cant replace it), and will not need to be insert with fragmentManager.

Comment: is the crash still the same as the logs you posted in your OP?

Comment: if yes, then i have edited the answer with a link to an article that explains why you are seeing the exception and how to solve it.

Comment: as anser for harikris. yes. it has the same log.

Comment: did you read this article i suggested on how to solve the issue? http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html